# Reposition rectangle after zooming

Tags: c++, c, delphi, math, lazarus

I have a rectangle defined by R1:x1,y1-x2,y2 and after applying zoom, I get the
rectangle R2:X1,Y1-X2,Y2.

```
+--------------+---+
|              |   |
|     R1       |   |
|              |   |
+--------------+   |
|              R2  |
+------------------+
```

As you can see, R2 is expanded based on R1's origin. Not my desired effect.

What I want to accomplish is to re-calculate the origin based on where was the
mouse pointer when the zooming operation was performed.

For example:

```
   +-----------------------+ 
   | +-----------------+   |
   | |  o              |   |
   | |       R1        |   |
   | |                 |   |
   | +-----------------+   |
   |            R2         |
   +-----------------------+
```

Here, the mouse pointer was set on point "o", then zoomed, resulting on a
rectangle R2. Please note R2 is not centered on R1, but a little displaced to
the right and bottom.

How can I re-position the origin after zooming?.

Comment: Please define "a little"

Comment: With "a little" I meant, the resulting rectangle will not be centered against the former one, but "centered" on the mouse pointer.

Comment: You can re-position the origin by, well, re-positioning the origin. You want the origin somewhere else, just put it there. This is a non-question.

Comment: No, I don't want the origin anywhere. The new origin must be moved because the zoomed rectangle is bigger, but the point "o" must be the same as in the former rectangle.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sort of, but not really.  In a video game you don't want the camera viewport to snap to where the mouse is positioned, you want it to zoom smoothly in/out of that position.

Comment: @leetNightshade I'm sure there's a well-defined question that could be asked, but it has not been asked.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Indeed, because it, like other problems, can be tricky to word into a sensible question.

Comment: If **o** is is a centre of R2, then xo=x1+(x2-x1)/2. Yes, this question needs a drawing :)

Comment: @user539484, no "o" is not the center, it's the point that shouldn't be moved, so R2 must be expanded on every direction keeping "o" at the same position. Imagine the user clicks on the point "o" then drag the mouse, the rectangle R2 must grow keeping that point at the same place.

Comment: @leonardorame, this is still very imaginary. Grab a sheet of paper and draw your transform in the cartesian coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a programming specific question, but a math problem.

If the mouse is in the center of the screen, each side expands equally. If the mouse is all the way to one side, the rectangle expands only in that direction. So you need to determine the size increase from a ratio.

So, we need to setup a few variables here: width_delta, height_delta, mouse_x_relative, mouse_y_relative, rect_width, rect_height.

- Width delta is the new width minus the old width.
- Height delta is the new height minus the old height.
- Mouse x relative is the x-coordinate  relative to the rect's left side
- Mouse y relative is the y-coordinate relative to the rect's top side

With each delta, when the mouse is perfectly centered, we can calculate the change in the rectangles sides with delta - delta / 2, and delta / 2.  This results in half of the delta going to the one side, the other half to the other.  So instead of dividing by 2, we need to find out how this relates to the mouse position and the size of the rect.

Easy enough: rect_width / mouse_x_relative.  Let's say a rect is width 10, mouse is in the center at 5, 10 / 5 is 2, causing the delta to be distributed equally to both sides of the rect.  So we need to divide the delta by rect_width / mouse_x_relative.

```
left_delta = width_delta / rect_width / mouse_x_relative
right_delta = width_delta - left_delta
```

But we can clean that up to be:

```
left_delta = width_delta * mouse_x_relative / rect_width
right_delta = width_delta - left_delta
```

I believe *that* should work with your expected behavior, unlike my last answer.  When you zoom in (shrink) the rect closes in on the mouse (centering), when you zoom out it moves away from the mouse (un-centering, if you will), the inverse of the way it moved in.

Comment: Yes, I think this will be the answer, tomorrow I'll create a sample program to test using your formulas. My program is an image viewer, and I need to zoom using the mouse pointer, for example, imagine a picture showing a face, when the user clicks on the eye and drag, the image is zoomed centered on the eye. Hope you understand.